# How to fix continuous logcat message when starting new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am creating an android application in java, and watched a tutorial on this by the YouTube channel Android Authority, where he replaces the layout .xml file of the starting activity with another java file. Also, the activities extend Activity instead of AppCompactActivity. I have done everything the same, and am attempting to start another activity from this one using Intent and startActivity(intent). However, doing this leads to logcat outputting a continuous stream of text attempting to create a new activity, yet it never succeeds and the screen remains on the first activity.

I have tried starting another activity that has a .xml layout file, and that has worked. It seems like the problem is with the .java layout file. I haven't found anything online that shows people having this same problem.

Starting class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(new MainMenuView(this));
}
```

MainMenuView class:

```
public MainMenuView(Context context){
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    activity = (Activity) mContext;
    intent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), FileSelect.class);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.start();
}

public void newActivity(){
    if (thingy){ //assigned true when a button is pressed
        thingy = false; 
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(new FileSelectView(this));
}
```

FileSelectView class:

```
public FileSelectView(Context context){
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    activity = (Activity) mContext;
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThreadTwo(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.start();
}
```

MainThread class (MainThread and MainThreadTwo are practically identical):

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private MainMenuView mainMenuView;
    private boolean running = true;
    private static Canvas canvas;

    MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainMenuView mainMenuView){
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.mainMenuView = mainMenuView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime;
        long timeBillis;
        long waitTime;
        int targetFPS = 30;
        long targetTime = 1000 / targetFPS;

        while (running){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized(surfaceHolder){
                    if (mainMenuView != null && canvas != null) {
                        this.mainMenuView.update();
                        this.mainMenuView.draw(canvas);
                    }
                    if (canvas != null){
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                    if (mainMenuView != null){
                        this.mainMenuView.newActivity();
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            timeBillis = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            waitTime = targetTime - timeBillis;

            if (timeBillis < targetTime) {
                try {
                    this.sleep(waitTime);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When starting a class with a .xml file layout, after calling startActivity(intent), logcat would print a few of the following messages, and the screen would update to the new activity. With the setup I use, after calling startActivity(intent), logcat endlessly alternates between printing out chunks of:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@ca0f529[FileSelect]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=78
D/ViewRootImpl@ca0f529[FileSelect]: setView = DecorView@1f110ae[FileSelect] touchMode=true
```

with the "fd=" number increasing by one, and:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@3ed1b35[MainMenu]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@3ed1b35[MainMenu]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1280,800] result=0x1 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
```

It would really help if anybody could understand what is happening here, I will try and help/rephrase if anybody does not understand parts of the question. Why are these output messages occurring continuously, and why is the new activity not appearing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your variable *running* to false, inside your while (in your MainThread class), after it reaches a certain condition. Your app had entered in an infinite loop, that's why your log has a lot of messages and activity doesn't appear.

Comment: No, I tried this and the messages still continued and the activity doesn't show up. I used System.out.println("foo") in the thread's while loop to check the log and see if the thread is still running. The thread stops, and the logcat messages continue.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't helped you.. One think that it's strange for me is the this.mainMenuView.newActivity(), because it looks like it'll call the startActivity again and enter in the MainThread cycle again and again.

Comment: Well, what I find interesting is that I can launch the starting activity class no problem from an XML file layout activity, but the same problems occur when I attempt to launch the second class. It makes me think there is something wrong with the class I'm trying to launch, but I can't figure out how it differs from the first activity.